# Calculate CTR (click-through-rate) and output as new field based on 3 distinct groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr, transpose

I have a dataframe that looks like so:

```
                             user_id           split_test_group  Exposed_Date        Exposed_Time                             event_type     platform       event_type_button    Event_Date          Event_Time       
 b861f69cb669766cc0d52bc2279332c0:   414   control     :27274   Min.   :2017-06-29   Length:142123      referrer_page_invite_action:  8896   iOS:135067              :133227   Min.   :2017-06-02   Length:142123     
 5ac762996eb6e8932fd2140e77a7a870:   376   tab_only    :67381   1st Qu.:2017-07-05   Class :character   referrer_page_viewed       :133227   Web:  7056   Link       :  1816   1st Qu.:2017-07-21   Class :character  
 00c26d8255da64576a9e3c5a2c1271eb:   298   tab_settings:47468   Median :2017-07-08   Mode  :character                                                     SMS        :  1727   Median :2017-08-04   Mode  :character  
 2d4fdc1606ad722a93a98882f9ccf331:   236                        Mean   :2017-07-12                                                                        link       :  1226   Mean   :2017-08-02                     
 4296772f2a0ce768d25573863c82968c:   236                        3rd Qu.:2017-07-20                                                                        email      :  1118   3rd Qu.:2017-08-17                     
 fe7a74a142b5774375ba64184d67a8e3:   212                        Max.   :2017-09-01                                                                        ShareDialog:  1062   Max.   :2017-09-01                     
 (Other)                         :140351                                                                                                                  (Other)    :  1947
```

I would like to use dplyr package to transpose the dataframe so I can count the number of referrer_page_viewes there were vs the number of referrer_page_invite_actions per **split_test_group** to create a CTR.

With this table I would like to calcuate CTR based on each split_test_group.

```
event_type                     split_test_group                         Total_Impressions
referrer_page_invite_action          control                            1892        
referrer_page_invite_action          tab_only                           4009        
referrer_page_invite_action          tab_settings                       2995        
referrer_page_viewed                 control                            25382       
referrer_page_viewed                 tab_only                           63372       
referrer_page_viewed                 tab_settings                       44473
```

Equation: Click-through rate (per user id) = referrer_page_invite_action # / referrer_page_viewed #

Desired output table would look like so (madeup values):

```
split_test_group | CTR
control             x%
tab_only            x%
tab_settings        x%
```

Comment: edited the data

Comment: added more information to make it more clear with new table @akrun

Comment: Brilliant - transmute - thats perfect - thank you so much. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I may need to normalize it since control had the highest % but far less in # of participants...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `pivot_wider` to reshape to 'wide' format and then do the division

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = event_type, values_from = Total_Impressions) %>% 
     transmute(split_test_group, CTR = 100 *referrer_page_invite_action/
            referrer_page_viewed )
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  split_test_group   CTR
  <chr>            <dbl>
1 control           7.45
2 tab_only          6.33
3 tab_settings      6.73
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(event_type = c("referrer_page_invite_action", 
"referrer_page_invite_action", "referrer_page_invite_action", 
"referrer_page_viewed", "referrer_page_viewed", "referrer_page_viewed"
), split_test_group = c("control", "tab_only", "tab_settings", 
"control", "tab_only", "tab_settings"), Total_Impressions = c(1892L, 
4009L, 2995L, 25382L, 63372L, 44473L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Hello  Akrun - thank you for response. I need to factor in field 'event_type' into this somehow. Basically sum the # of referrer_page_viewes there were vs the number of referrer_page_invite_actions per split_test_group to create a CTR. I ran your code  and seem to get NAs bc  of  that.

Comment: @Dinho what is the formula with event_type

Comment: there is  not formula - the two groups are described as:  “referral_page_view”: user views the page for sending referral invites 
“referrer_page_invite_action”: users clicks the button to send a referral invite

Comment: @Dinho I see that you have 8896 and 133227.  how does te values change with those info

Comment: The was a populated dataset given to me. Those values are generated based on each user_id and the distinct event_time in the  dataframe. I was thinking to to use CTR to see which  'event_type' had the best  impact on 'clicks'.

Comment: @Dinho it is not clear from your example what you expect as output as the expected output is just made up values

Comment: @Dinho Are you calculating 27274/8896